# Pandas, Bar Chart Annotations

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, charts

**How to properly give Annotations to Pandas Bar Charts?**

I'm following [Bar Chart Annotations with Pandas and MPL](http://robertmitchellv.com/blog/bar-chart-annotations-with-pandas-and-mpl.html), but somehow I can't make it into my own code -- [this is as far as I can go](https://gist.github.com/suntong/d09ef3400756a73af73d). What's wrong?

I've also found the following code [from here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html):

```
def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
```

But I don't how to apply that to my code either. Please help.

UPDATE:

Thank you @CT Zhu, for the answer. However, in your horizontal bars, you are still placing the text on top of bars, but I need the text show up within or along them, like this from my referenced article,

[image]

where s/he says,

> "I am very parital to horizontal bar charts, as I really think they are easier to read, however, I understand that a lot of people would rather see this chart implemented in a regular bar chart. So, here is the code to do that; you will notice that a few things have changed in order to create the annotation"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your `autolabel` function is expecting a list of `patches`, sssuming your plot only those bars as its `patches`, we could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'score':np.random.randn(6),
                   'person':[x*3 for x in list('ABCDEF')]})

def autolabel(rects):
    x_pos = [rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2. for rect in rects]
    y_pos = [rect.get_y() + 1.05*rect.get_height() for rect in rects]
    #if height constant: hbars, vbars otherwise
    if (np.diff([plt.getp(item, 'width') for item in rects])==0).all():
        scores = [plt.getp(item, 'height') for item in rects]
    else:
        scores = [plt.getp(item, 'width') for item in rects]
    # attach some text labels
    for rect, x, y, s in zip(rects, x_pos, y_pos, scores):
        ax.text(x, 
                y,
                '%s'%s,
                ha='center', va='bottom')

ax = df.set_index(['person']).plot(kind='barh', figsize=(10,7), 
              color=['dodgerblue', 'slategray'], fontsize=13)

ax.set_alpha(0.8)
ax.set_title("BarH")#,fontsize=18)
autolabel(ax.patches)
```

[image]

```
ax = df.set_index(['person']).plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10,7), 
              color=['dodgerblue', 'slategray'], fontsize=13)

ax.set_alpha(0.8)
ax.set_title("Bar")#,fontsize=18)
autolabel(ax.patches)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Accordint to the aformentioned *Bar Chart Annotations with Pandas and MPL*, `autolabel` would be different for vertical and horizontal bars. Apparently, the code I copied is for vertical bars. Could you change it to horizontal bars, so that the text show up *within* or along the bar instead of on top of it please?   
Also, why the value are all `0.5`? I need to annotations with the real value of the `score`s. Thanks

Comment: See edit.  That just requires determining if the plot is a bar plot or a barh plot.

Comment: Thank you @CT Zhu, for the answer. I've updated my OP to further explain what I meant by *"within or along the bar"*.

Comment: Ok, I can settle with this. Thanks again @CT Zhu.