# Pandas Bar plot, how to annotate grouped horizontal bar charts

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I ask this question because I haven't found a working example on **how to annotate grouped horizontal Pandas bar charts** yet. I'm aware of the following two:

- [Annotate bars with values on Pandas bar plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots)
- [Pandas, Bar Chart Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111620/pandas-bar-chart-annotations)

But they are all about vertical bar charts. I.e., either don't have a solution for horizontal bar chart, or it is not fully working.

After several weeks working on this issue, I finally am able to ask the question with a sample code, which is almost what I want, just not 100% working. Need your help to reach for that 100%.

Here we go, the [full code is uploaded here](https://gist.github.com/suntong/3785994e313a0cb3e406). The result looks like this:

[image: Pandas chart]

You can see that it is almost working, just the label is not placed at where I want and I can't move them to a better place myself. Besides, because the top of the chart bar is used for displaying error bar, so what I really want is to move the annotate text toward the y-axis, *line up nicely* on either left or right side of y-axis, depending the X-value. E.g., this is what my colleagues can do with MS Excel:

[image: MS Excel chart]

Is this possible for Python to do that with Pandas chart?

I'm including the code from my above url for the annotation, one is my all-that-I-can-do, and the other is for the reference (from `In [23]`):

```
# my all-that-I-can-do
def autolabel(rects):
    #if height constant: hbars, vbars otherwise
    if (np.diff([plt.getp(item, 'width') for item in rects])==0).all():
        x_pos = [rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2. for rect in rects]
        y_pos = [rect.get_y() + 1.05*rect.get_height() for rect in rects]
        scores = [plt.getp(item, 'height') for item in rects]
    else:
        x_pos = [rect.get_width()+.3 for rect in rects]
        y_pos = [rect.get_y()+.3*rect.get_height() for rect in rects]
        scores = [plt.getp(item, 'width') for item in rects]
    # attach some text labels
    for rect, x, y, s in zip(rects, x_pos, y_pos, scores):
        ax.text(x, 
                y,
                #'%s'%s,
                str(round(s, 2)*100)+'%',
                ha='center', va='bottom')

# for the reference 
ax.bar(1. + np.arange(len(xv)), xv, align='center')
# Annotate with text
ax.set_xticks(1. + np.arange(len(xv)))
for i, val in enumerate(xv):
    ax.text(i+1, val/2, str(round(val, 2)*100)+'%', va='center',
ha='center', color='black')
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I changed a bit the way you construct your data for simplicity:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
sns.set_style("white") #for aesthetic purpose only

# fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar'], 100),
                   'B': np.random.choice(['one', 'two', 'three'], 100),
                   'C': np.random.choice(['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4'], 100),
                   'D': np.random.randint(-10,11,100),
                   'E': np.random.randn(100)})

p = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A','B'], columns='C', values='D')
e = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A','B'], columns='C', values='E')

ax = p.plot(kind='barh', xerr=e, width=0.85)

for r in ax.patches:
    if r.get_x() < 0: # it it's a negative bar
        ax.text(0.25, # set label on the opposite side
                r.get_y() + r.get_height()/5., # y
                "{:" ">7.1f}%".format(r.get_x()*100), # text
                bbox={"facecolor":"red", 
                      "alpha":0.5,
                      "pad":1},
                fontsize=10, family="monospace", zorder=10)
    else:
        ax.text(-1.5, # set label on the opposite side
                r.get_y() + r.get_height()/5., # y
                "{:" ">6.1f}%".format(r.get_width()*100), 
                bbox={"facecolor":"green",
                      "alpha":0.5,
                      "pad":1},
                fontsize=10, family="monospace", zorder=10)
plt.tight_layout()
```

which gives:

[image: barh plot error bar annotated]

I plot the label depending on the mean value and put it on the other side of the 0-line so you're pretty sure that it will never overlap to something else, except an error bar sometimes. I set a box behind the text so it reflects the value of the mean.
There are some values you'll need to adjust depending on your figure size so the labels fit right, like:

- `width=0.85`
- `+r.get_height()/5. # y`
- `"pad":1`
- `fontsize=10`
- `"{:" ">6.1f}%".format(r.get_width()*100)` : set total amount of char in the label (here, 6 minimum, fill with white space on the right if less than 6 char). It needs `family="monospace"`

Tell me if something isn't clear.

HTH

Comment: @xpt, ok, let me know if you don't understand something. I've made some modification since you commented.

Comment: excellent, excellent! Sorry for responding late. The only question I have is, from the whole code I didn't see why it needs to `import seaborn`, but when I commented out that line, it still works, but the chart looks uglier. I guess that answer the question, but why is that? Thx again.

Comment: @xpt, yes, see line 5 (`sns.set_style...`), I commented that it was for aesthetic purpose.

Comment: Thanks, first time to know that seaborn can be used this way. I.e., not a single seaborn specific functionality is used, yet it is doing the beautification behind the scene. Great.